# How can I set the default URL Mapping when using the Rest Profile in Grails 3.1.7?

Tags: grails, grails-3.1

I am building an app using the Rest Profile. I would like all the requests to be available at /api/.

For example, a controller BookController should be available at /api/books, a controller LessonController should be /api/lessons.

By default, it is /books and /lessons. How do I change this?

Answer (score 1):

In grails-app/conf/application.yml, try adding this:

```
server:
    context-path: '/api'
```

Comment: Thanks jnunderwood. Just wondering. With the rest profile, can I still use the controllers generated by Grails? For example http://<app>/Book/index and also http://<app>/api/book ?

Comment: @bhushan154 In grails-app/controllers/api/UrlMappings.groovy (or somewhere in the controllers directory), you can add something like this: `"/api/book/count"( controller: 'book', action: 'count' )`. I'm not sure about using the controllers generated by the Book domain object. I would tend to use one or the other and not both, but it may work.